# Google App Engine (Python) - Import Fails

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import

I have a file structure like so:

```
app.yaml
something/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    test.py
```

I have URL set up to run `tests.py` in `app.yaml`:

```
...
- url: /test
  script: something/test.py
```

`test.py` imports `models.py`

When I try to navigate to `http://myapp.appspot.com/test/` I get the following error:

> Error: Server Error
>   The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the > query that caused it

And, when I check the logs on the dashboard I see the following error occurred:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named models
```

How do I import the file properly?

Cheers,

Pete

Comment: if you could show us your code - we might spot something you may be missing.

Comment: What happens when you run the app in the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

inside test.py you can write at the top something like:

```
from something.models import *
```

This will import your models.
For corrective code though - the wildcard '*' is not great and you explicitly import the models your using:

```
from something.models import ModelName, OtherModel
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

test.py should have `imports models`, not `imports models.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try to import `models` like this:

```
import something.models as models
```